# How to get each enum value as a list of Strings?

Tags: java, enums

```
public enum CountryDefaultAddressEnum {
    // Country or Region , Contact Name, Street Address, City, State, ZIP Code
    US_CAL("US", "CA Address", "2065 Hamilton Avenue", " ", "San Jose", "CA",
            "95125"),
    US_SJ("US", "CA Address", "201 South Fourth Street", " ", "San Jose", "CA",
            "95112");

    private CountryDefaultAddressEnum(String countryOrRegion,
            String contactName, String streetAddress, String streetAddress2,
            String city, String state, String zipCode) {
        this.countryOrRegion = countryOrRegion;
        this.contactName = contactName;
        this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
        this.streetAddress2 = streetAddress2;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

public String getValue() {
    return String.format("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s", countryOrRegion, contactName, streetAddress, streetAddress2, city, state, zipCode);
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    for(CountryDefaultAddressEnum countryAddr : US_CAL.values()) {
      System.out.println(countryAddr + ": " + countryAddr.getValue());
    }
}
```

How do I get all the strings of this enum?
I want something like:

```
CountryDefaultAddressEnum.US_CAL.getValue()=("US", "CA Address", "2065 Hamilton Avenue",
                                             " ", "San Jose", "CA", "95125")
```

Comment: That's not a valid enum.  Where is your constructor?  Can you post it please?

Comment: Add a method `List<String> getValue` that returns the proper list with all the values in the `enum`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question, you'll want a method that returns a String with the values of your enum.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    for(CountryDefaultAddressEnum countryAddr : CountryDefaultAddressEnum.values()) {
        System.out.println(countryAddr + ": " + countryAddr.getValue());
    }
}

public enum CountryDefaultAddressEnum {

    // Country or Region , Contact Name, Street Address, City, State, ZIP Code
    US_CAL("US", "CA Address", "2065 Hamilton Avenue", " ", "San Jose", "CA",
            "95125"),
    US_SJ("US", "CA Address", "201 South Fourth Street", " ", "San Jose", "CA",
            "95112");

    private String countryOrRegion;
    private String contactName;
    private String streetAddress;
    private String streetAddress2;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipCode;

    private CountryDefaultAddressEnum(String countryOrRegion,
            String contactName, String streetAddress, String streetAddress2,
            String city, String state, String zipCode) {
        this.countryOrRegion = countryOrRegion;
        this.contactName = contactName;
        this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
        this.streetAddress2 = streetAddress2;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.zipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return String.format("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s", countryOrRegion, contactName, streetAddress, streetAddress2, city, state, zipCode);
    }
}
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: for(CountryDefaultAddressEnum countryAddr : CountryDefaultAddressEnum.US_CAL.values()) {
            System.out.println(countryAddr + ": " + countryAddr.getValue());
        }

Comment: @RuchiSethi Then you would use US_CAL.getValue()

Comment: for(CountryDefaultAddressEnum countryAddr : US_CAL.values())  is also getting values for both constants

Comment: US_CAL.getValue() works ..:) I was using it in for loop, shouldn't have

Comment: @RuchiSethi Good to hear :-) Check my answer so your question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
List<String> defaultAddresses = new ArrayList<String>();
for(CountryDefaultAddressEnum countryAddr : CountryDefaultAddressEnum.values())
{
    defaultAddresses.add(countryAddr.toString());

}
```

Comment: I've edited the code, it should compile now (my edit still needs to be approved, so it may not show right now)